# Echo content on the same line in jQuery Terminal

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-terminal

I've been looking through the documentation for [jQuery Terminal](http://terminal.jcubic.pl/) but found nothing. Basically, I'm trying to echo the following:

[image: jQuery Terminal]

Here `v0.8.7` should be a link, but when I try to echo the string using `.echo(string,{raw:true})` the ASCII art gets distorted:

```
term.echo(
    '      __ _____                     ________                              __\n'+
    '     / // _  /__ __ _____ ___ __ _/__  ___/__ ___ ______ __ __  __ ___  / /\n'+
    ' __ / // // // // // _  // _// // / / // _  // _//     // //  \\/ // _ \\/ /\n'+
    '/  / // // // // // ___// / / // / / // ___// / / / / // // /\\  // // / /__\n'+
    '\\___//____ \\\\___//____//_/ _\\_  / /_//____//_/ /_/_/_//_//_/ /_/ \\__\\_\\___/\n'+
    '          \\/              /____/                                     <a href="http://terminal.jcubic.pl/" target="_blank" title="jQueryTerminal Website">v'+term.version()+'</a>',
    {raw:true}
);
```

[image]

I tried using 2 separate echo calls, but the version number is pushed to a new line. How can I add the version number at the end of the ASCII art without it going into a new line?

Here is my current code:

```
term.echo(
    '      __ _____                     ________                              __\n'+
    '     / // _  /__ __ _____ ___ __ _/__  ___/__ ___ ______ __ __  __ ___  / /\n'+
    ' __ / // // // // // _  // _// // / / // _  // _//     // //  \\/ // _ \\/ /\n'+
    '/  / // // // // // ___// / / // / / // ___// / / / / // // /\\  // // / /__\n'+
    '\\___//____ \\\\___//____//_/ _\\_  / /_//____//_/ /_/ /_//_//_/ /_/ \\__\\_\\___/\n'+
    '          \\/              /____/                                     '
);
term.echo('<a href="http://terminal.jcubic.pl/" target="_blank" title="jQueryTerminal Website">v'+term.version()+'</a>',{raw:true});
```

[image]

Live demo: http://suchmail.eu/Hunpony/djdavid98/cli
(use the command `ver`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading through [**@Giacomo1968**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24346832/echo-content-on-the-same-line-in-jquery-terminal/24348085#24348085), I managed to find the ultimate solution without any need for extra CSS.

```
term.echo(
    '      __ _____                     ________                              __\n'+
    '     / // _  /__ __ _____ ___ __ _/__  ___/__ ___ ______ __ __  __ ___  / /\n'+
    ' __ / // // // // // _  // _// // / / // _  // _//     // //  \\/ // _ \\/ /\n'+
    '/  / // // // // // ___// / / // / / // ___// / / / / // // /\\  // // / /__\n'+
    '\\___//____ \\\\___//____//_/ _\\_  / /_//____//_/ /_/_/_//_//_/ /_/ \\__\\_\\___/\n'+
    '          \\/              /____/                                           '.replace(new RegExp(" {" + (term.version().length+1) + "}$"), ''),
    {finalize: function($div){
        $div.children().last().append('<a href="http://terminal.jcubic.pl/" target="_blank" title="jQueryTerminal Website">v'+term.version()+'</a>')
    }}
);
```

Using the `finalize` option mentioned by him, I was able to add some additional HTML to the last `<div>` using jQuery.

[image]

Comment: You will get different looking version if string version change to `0.10.10`. In source code there this: `replace(new RegExp(" {" + version_string.length + "}$"), ' ');` so the version is always aligned to the right.

Answer (score 3):

Okay this was quite interesting. Basically the [`jQuery Terminal`](http://terminal.jcubic.pl) `echo` function only operates in a few different modes that don’t mix methods within an `echo` call.

But there is a way to effectively do what you are looking for by using the `finalize` callback function as explained in [the documentation for `echo`](http://terminal.jcubic.pl/api_reference.php#echo):

> **finalize** — which is callback function with one argument the div
> container

That is key. If you look at the source HTML that is output from [`jQuery Terminal`](http://terminal.jcubic.pl) when it `echo`’s content you can see it is all basically a pile of `<div>` elements with a width of `100%` and the ASCII inside of it.

```
<div style="width: 100%;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;__&nbsp;_____&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;________&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;__</div>
```

So when you try to `echo` on the next line line this:

```
term.echo('<a href="http://terminal.jcubic.pl/" target="_blank" title="jQueryTerminal Website">v'+term.version()+'</a>',{raw:true});
```

What happens is another `<div style="width: 100%;">` is generated which knocks the line down. And because it is `raw:true` it means that it cannot be mixed with the `echo` above it.

But by using `finalize` and acting on the `div` that contains the link you can do this:

```
term.echo('<a href="http://terminal.jcubic.pl/" target="_blank" title="jQueryTerminal Website">v'+term.version()+'</a>',
     { raw:true,
       finalize: function(div) {
          div
         .css("width", "720px")
         .css("text-align", "right")
         .css("margin-top", "-1em")
         ;
       }
     });
```

The magic is all CSS and jQuery setting the CSS. The width gets set to `720px`, the `text-align` is set to the right now and then the `margin-top` is set to `-1em` so the line is pushed up exactly 1 line. Here is a screenshot of what it looks like with these adjustments in place:

[image]

So for all intents and purposes, it visually looks the same. The caveat of this method is you can never tell how browsers will behave to CSS like this. So be sure to test it in a few browsers. But if it chokes, just tweak the CSS that gets set in `finalize` and you should be able to come up with a combo that works well across browsers.

Comment: Using the `finalize` option I found a solution without any need for extra CSS. Thank you for your help!

Comment: *(by the way, you're missing an "H" from "What happens")*

Answer (score 2):

The reason why this is happening is because \n in html is ignored, all whitespace characters are replaced by one space. In order to have this in one echo is to use `<br />` instead of `\n` or wrap each line with `<div>`. This is how inserting html work, because terminal just append raw data. The other option is to use `finalize`, to alter text text, as other answers suggest.